# PHP Application Not Working Cant Write PDF File

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I'm working on http://usborrow.com. The site used to be able to output the data to a PDF, however I am now getting the following error:

```
 Error: [2] /home/usborrow/public_html/gfe.php on line 218
fopen(docs/30b583784503f7dc61999d234c67e204.pdf) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory
```

The script around line 218 is as follows:

```
 // Create the pdf
 $pdfmaker = new pdftk_php();
 $pdfmaker->make_pdf($fdf_data_strings, $fdf_data_names, $fields_hidden, $fields_readonly,      $pdf_original, $pdf_filename);

    // Create the attachment and params
    $fileatt = '/'.$pdf_filename;
    $fileatttype = "application/pdf";
    $fileattname = $offer->hashval.'.pdf';
    $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    fclose($file);
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
```

I've tried changing the permissions on the Docs folder, however it's still not working. Any support would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its not for the kind of read .. its for the path

try this before the fopen:

```
if (!is_dir("docs") {
  mkdir("docs");
}
```

Comment: Fixed it. pdftk wasn't being loaded

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what file mode `rb` is...but I think the one you're wanting is `r+`.

Comment: from php.net - you can also use 'b' to force binary mode